# Using registers in different terminals

Tags: register, window-management

I sometimes have multiple xterm windows open and run vim in both of them. Is there any way to copy text from one window to the other using registers if I don't have '+clipboard' enabled?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open a new xterm, run `vim -u NONE -N` (vim with unsourced .vimrc to make sure that no plugin interferes)
2. Yank a word with `yiw`, yank another word with `"ayiw`
3. Run `:reg` to check how the registers "0 and "a look like.
4. Open a new xterm and start vim again with `vim -u NONE -N`. I am now unable to paste either of the two words yanked before. Running `:reg` show that indeed the registers "0 and "a look different than the ones in my first xterm window.

I understand that would I have vim with '+clipboard' enabled, I could use the "+ register. But what can I do if I don't want have this option and don't want to open my two buffers in the same vim instance, but instead in two different xterms?

Comment: Or use something like this: https://github.com/ardagnir/united-front

Comment: This sounds weird: you want the effect of X-integration without actual X-integration. Can't you simply install a proper Vim?

Comment: No: you need both `+clipboard` and `+xterm_clipboard`, and only the contents of the clipboard is shared, via the system clipboard.  Other registers are not shared.

Comment: @romainl: Not the X-integration was the key point of my question, but rather register sharing across different vim sessions as I want to work with multiple registers not only with "+.
Register sharing across vim sessions works with Christian Brabandt's answer or VanLasers comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registers are not shared between different Vim sessions. If you want that, then you have to store and load the data from a file. I think, the Yankring plugin does something like this.

Also it should be possible to write your viminfo using `:wv` file after you put something into your desired register and load it from the other vim session using `:rv`. See also the [faq](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-17.3)